# Do I need to install XCode4 in order to

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4, xcode4

Do I need to install XCode4 (and iOS SDK 4.3) in order to install my app on iPhone's with iOS 4.3.2 installed on them?

I've installed the app on my iPhone which I just installed iOS 4.3.2 on but I thought it may just have worked because I had installed it previously on that phone when I had an older iOS version.

By the way, I'm using XCode version 3.2.5

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to test on iOS 4.3 devices with Xcode 3.2.6.

Comment: Great! How about XCode 3.2.5 though?